# How can I change package.json to have the newest version of axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

Okay so my npm audit requires me to review this file manually and it apparently needs the newest version of axios(0.21.1) so how can I rebuild it?

This is the error btw:

Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance

High            Server-Side Request Forgery

Package         axios

Patched in      >=0.21.1

Dependency of   apify

Path            apify > apify-client > axios

```
{
  "_from": "axios@^0.20.0",
  "_id": "axios@0.20.0",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-ANA4rr2BDcmmAQLOKft2fufrtuvlqR+cXNNinUmvfeSNCOF98PZL+7M/v1zIdGo7OLjEA9J2gXJL+j4zGsl0bA==",
  "_location": "/apify-client/axios",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "range",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "axios@^0.20.0",
    "name": "axios",
    "escapedName": "axios",
    "rawSpec": "^0.20.0",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "^0.20.0"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/apify-client"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.20.0.tgz",
  "_shasum": "057ba30f04884694993a8cd07fa394cff11c50bd",
  "_spec": "axios@^0.20.0",
  "_where": "C:\\Users\\Janek\\Desktop\\apify7\\my-new-project\\node_modules\\apify-client",
  "author": {
    "name": "Matt Zabriskie"
  },
  "browser": {
    "./lib/adapters/http.js": "./lib/adapters/xhr.js"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/axios/axios/issues"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "bundlesize": [
    {
      "path": "./dist/axios.min.js",
      "threshold": "5kB"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "follow-redirects": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "deprecated": "Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410",
  "description": "Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bundlesize": "^0.17.0",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "grunt": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-banner": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-eslint": "^20.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.13.3",
    "grunt-ts": "^6.0.0-beta.19",
    "grunt-webpack": "^1.0.18",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-ajax": "^0.1.13",
    "karma-opera-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sauce-launcher": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.2",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "sinon": "^4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.1",
    "url-search-params": "^0.10.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/axios/axios",
  "jsdelivr": "dist/axios.min.js",
  "keywords": [
    "xhr",
    "http",
    "ajax",
    "promise",
    "node"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "name": "axios",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/axios/axios.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production grunt build",
    "coveralls": "cat coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js",
    "examples": "node ./examples/server.js",
    "fix": "eslint --fix lib/**/*.js",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "start": "node ./sandbox/server.js",
    "test": "grunt test && bundlesize",
    "version": "npm run build && grunt version && git add -A dist && git add CHANGELOG.md bower.json package.json"
  },
  "typings": "./index.d.ts",
  "unpkg": "dist/axios.min.js",
  "version": "0.20.0"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the command `npm install axios` and it will automatically update axios and the package.json for you.

Comment: but it doesnt if the package.json is in node_modules apparently

Comment: That can happen when you have libraries that have an older version of axios as part of their dependencies. In that case, axios will not update if you run the above command.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$ npm uninstall axios
$ npm i axios --save
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using yarn, run the following command:

```
yarn add axios
```